# gdb pretty printer stops working if I rerun my program

Tags: c++, gdb

If I use the command run inside gdb to rerun my program I can no longer pretty print my c++ objects like vectors:

```
$ gdb ./some_program
(gdb) br some_where
(gdb) run
(gdb) print some_vector # the vector is pretty printed
(gdb) run
(gdb) print some_vector # the vector is no longer pretty printed
```

Here's a sample code I used and its actual gdb session:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                       using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> v{1};
    cout << v[0] << endl;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to see  this message "Start it from the beginning? (y or n) " 
when you rerun your code?

Comment: Please show your actual gdb session rather than an executive summary.

Comment: I think you code  has a problem not a gdb why don't you post your code ?

Comment: I added the program and my gdb session. I hope this is clear enough now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely [this libstdc++ pretty printers bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68448).

You can apply [this patch](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-11/msg02418.html) to you currently installed pretty printers or update whole gcc to a more recent version.

Comment: According to [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-11/msg02517.html) this patch introduces a regression. Besides I can't find the hook.in in my system.

Comment: No, regression was introduced by earlier patch by Siva Chandra: https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2014-09/msg02518.html. This patch (https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-11/msg02418.html) fixes that introduced regression.

Comment: I can't find hook.in file either.

Comment: Ok but do I need to recompile libstdc++. How can I apply the patch on my local machine?

Comment: No, it's python code, it need not to be recompiled. Just apply it with `patch` tool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150191/discussion-between-brahim-and-ks1322).